Jira automations - need to send a single email with content of a lookup, but Jira sends an email for each lookup item instead
Steps in the Jira Automation:

On incoming webhook, run a JQL with appropriate Jira results (works fine)
Run a "lookup" with the same query to store the information (Works fine)
Transition selected Jira's (Works fine)
comment on each Jira "Transitioned by automation" (Works fine)
Then I would like to send an email using the Lookup to list out the changed Jira's, but it send an email for every Jira in the query because it's looping through each Jira to do the transition.

I tried to create a branch to only send a single email, but it branched on every loop.  I scoured through all of the available actions but nothing seems to do this particular thing.  I also looked into how to trigger action "B" from action "A", where action "B"B would be send an email with a Lookup (if it can be passed between actions) but it seems that calling actions is (surprisingly) also not available in Jira.
